# Find all shortest paths between all pairs of nodes in NetworkX

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx, graph-theory, shortest-path

I am trying to get all shortest paths between all pairs of nodes in an undirected unweighted graph. I am currently using [`nx.all_pairs_shortest_path()`](https://networkx.org/documentation/networkx-1.9/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.unweighted.all_pairs_shortest_path.html#all-pairs-shortest-path), but I don't understand why it only returns one shortest path for every pair of nodes. There are cycles in my graph so there should exist multiple shortest paths between certain nodes. Any suggestions?

Comment: *"but I don't understand why it only returns one shortest path for every pair of nodes"* Because that's what this function does. It finds a shortest path for every pair of nodes.

Comment: Also, that may not be the case here, but it's possible to have a cycle in a graph and yet not have more than one shortest path per pair of node. For instance, any cycle graph with an odd number of nodes will have a unique shortest path for every pair of nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I stumbled upon this problem myself and arrived her in my quest for a solution. unfortunately networkx doesn't have a function to calculate all the shortest pathes for every pair of node. Moreover the answer from Igor Michetti wasn't giving what i wanted at all but it might have been tweekable.

The answer from math_noob was good because it was close enough for me to make up a solution but the problem was that it was way way too slow.

```py
def single_source_shortest_paths(graph,source):
    shortest_paths_dict = {}
    for node in graph:
        shortest_paths_dict[node] = list(nx.all_shortest_paths(graph,source,node))
    return shortest_paths_dict

def all_shortest_paths(graph):
    for source in graph:
        yield source, single_source_shortest_paths(source)
```

So i went back on networkx documentation and try to find one last time if there was any function i could use. but there was none so i decided i would implment it myself.So i first tried to implement everything by had which was a bit chaotic to only realise that it was a bit better but not that much so i decided i would try to look into the source code and found there a holy grail which is the `nx.predecessor` function.

This function is called on the graph and the source node only so it doesn't depends on the target node and it is the one doing most of the hard work. So i just recreated the function `single_source_shortest_paths` but by calling only once `nx.predecessor` per source node and then doing the same as `all_shortest_path` which only consist of calling another function with the right arguments.

```py
def single_source_shortest_paths_pred(graph,source):
    shortest_paths_dict = {}
    pred = nx.predecessor(graph,source)
    for node in graph:
        shortest_paths_dict[node] = list(nx.algorithms.shortest_paths.generic._build_paths_from_predecessors([source], node, pred))
    return shortest_paths_dict
```

In terms of time `nx.predecessor` takes the majority of the time to execute so the second function is around n times faster where n is the number of nodes in the graph

Answer (score 5):

Iterate over all nodes in the graph:

```
results = []
for n1 in G.nodes():
    for n2 in G.nodes():
        shortest_path = nx.single_source_dijkstra(G, source=n1, target=n2, weight=f)
        results.append(shortest_path)
```

Answer (score 2):

I may be late, but I just came across the same problem and this was my solution:

```
 def all_shortest_paths(G):
    a = list(nx.all_pairs_shortest_path(G))
    all_sp_list = []
    for n in range(len(G.nodes)):
      a1 = a[n][1]
      for k,v in a1.items():
        all_sp_list.append(len(v))
    return all_sp_list
```

Every other way I tried was getting very very slow because my graph had a bunch of nodes, so this was my fastest solution.

Comment: In my case, I just needed the shortest paths lenghts for plotting a histogram. If you want the shortest path data, you will have to tweek the code.

Answer (score 2):

[image: demo graph]

The working code below returns a dictionary.  The keys are (source, target) tuples for quick lookup, and the values are (minimum distance, path) tuples.

```
import pandas as pd  # dataframes
import networkx as nx  # networks a.k.a graphs
from pprint import pprint  # prettty print


def new_pandas_edgelist():
    return pd.DataFrame(
        {
            "source": ["A", "A", "B", "C"],
            "target": ["B", "C", "D", "D"],
            "distance": [10, 20, 30, 40],
        }
    )


def new_graph(df: pd.DataFrame) -> nx.classes.graph.Graph:
    G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, edge_attr=["distance"], create_using=nx.Graph)
    return G


def every_shortest_path(G):
    return {(src, tgt): a_shortest_path(G, src, tgt) for src in G for tgt in G}


def a_shortest_path(G, source, target, weight="distance"):
    return nx.single_source_dijkstra(G, source, target, weight=weight)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    df_edges = new_pandas_edgelist()
    G = new_graph(df_edges)
    print("")
    print("every shortest path...")
    pprint(every_shortest_path(G))

# every shortest path...
# {('A', 'A'): (0, ['A']),
#  ('A', 'B'): (10, ['A', 'B']),
#  ('A', 'C'): (20, ['A', 'C']),
#  ('A', 'D'): (40, ['A', 'B', 'D']),
#  ('B', 'A'): (10, ['B', 'A']),
#  ('B', 'B'): (0, ['B']),
#  ('B', 'C'): (30, ['B', 'A', 'C']),
#  ('B', 'D'): (30, ['B', 'D']),
#  ('C', 'A'): (20, ['C', 'A']),
#  ('C', 'B'): (30, ['C', 'A', 'B']),
#  ('C', 'C'): (0, ['C']),
#  ('C', 'D'): (40, ['C', 'D']),
#  ('D', 'A'): (40, ['D', 'B', 'A']),
#  ('D', 'B'): (30, ['D', 'B']),
#  ('D', 'C'): (40, ['D', 'C']),
#  ('D', 'D'): (0, ['D'])}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).